# Sned keepalive commands like "PWD" to the tcplistener from windows command prompt

Tags: command-line, azure, timeout, ftp-client

Since I TCP listener is being implemented in Azure worker role listening for incoming request on port 21.

While connecting from windows command prompt(cmd.exe) to FTP,connection gets successfull.

However when i issue PUT command on large files like 600MB, like

```
       ftp>> put localfile remotefile
```

Exactly after 1 minute of data transfer ,the connection gets disconnection with error as 
"Connection closed by Host".Since during large data transfer,the control connection of FTP would be idle.

I suspect that since Azure load balancer terminates the connection which are idle for 1 minute.

Any your inputs whether is it Azure load balancer which terminates the connection OR is there any registry setting on windows where i can increase the timeout of ftp client OR any firewall settings which kills the idle connections.

I tried following code to send the keep alive messages from tcpclient to tcplistener but could not succeed.

```
           int size = sizeof(UInt32);
                UInt32 on = 1;
                UInt32 keepAliveInterval = 10000; //Send a packet once every 10 seconds.
                UInt32 retryInterval = 1000; //If no response, resend every second.
                byte[] inArray = new byte[size * 3];
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(on), 0, inArray, 0, size);
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(keepAliveInterval), 0, inArray, size, size);
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(retryInterval), 0, inArray, size * 2, size);
```

Connection.OutboundTcpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, True)
                    Connection.OutboundTcpClient.Client.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, inArray,null);

Comment: The Windows Azure load balancer terminates idle connections, but an active file upload wouldn't be an idle connection.

Comment: Plus, that one minute idle timeout is a bit oldish yet. Now it is something like 5 minutes. So terminating after 1 minute is something different than Azure Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,i realized that it is not because of Azure load balancer..Since in FTP service,we have two connection 1.Control/Command connection 2.Data connection. During huge file upload,control connection would be idle..Due to my corporate firewall settings,it closes the control connection which leads to close of ftp client. Workaround would be send keep alive message from client to server on control channel..how to send the messages at socket level.Please refer to original post for code details.